# how to resize an image and save it to storage using save function

Tags: python, django

[image]

[image]

[image]

how can i modify my save function to solve this problem ?
i have a storage and when i wanted to upload an image i encountered this error .

Comment: Use the approach from the duplicate question. The approach is the same whether you crop or resize the image using PIL/Pillow.